# magento jquery-1.10.2.min blocking other script files

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, blocks

Am using `magento 1.9.3`, i creating custom file called `declaration`.

In declaration page am adding

> `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This script blocking some function. Like `ajax cart`, `mouse hover menu expand`, ect...

How can i fix this issue.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yess in console i geting error

Comment: Is your site loading another version of jQuery as well? Is v1.10.2 being loaded too?

Comment: @BenCrook: The console error https://ibb.co/ehhkEQ

Comment: @jscar: Yes  loading `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/sliver-exchange/js/etheme/coolbaby/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @jscar: After adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` only am facing this problem. Any idea to fix this issue ?

Comment: I think you need to look into using each in noConflict mode.

Comment: @jscar Am added `var jQuery=$.noConflict();` in `js\etheme\coolbaby\noconflict.js` but no use

Comment: @jscar If am wrong please tell me your suggestion

Comment: you need to do the noConflict declaration in the head of the html just after the jQuery is loaded. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're loading jQuery twice. If this is the case remove one of the version (preferably the older one).

Comment: which one i want to remove `v1.10.2` or `v1.7.1` and thanks for your answer

Comment: I would remove `1.7.1` as it's older, if that doesn't fix it try removing `1.10.2` instead.